# Date arithmetic within an IN clause in a Teradata SQL query

Tags: sql, teradata

The first two queries here works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM sys_calendar.calendar
WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATE) - 365 
                        AND CAST('2013-06-01' AS DATE) - 1;

SELECT * FROM sys_calendar.calendar
WHERE calendar_date IN ('2012-06-01', '2013-06-03');
```

However, the next two queries throw the error

> SELECT Failed.  [3706] Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ','.

It appears that the `CAST` is throwing off the IN clause, but I don't understand why. What is going on here?

```
SELECT * FROM sys_calendar.calendar
WHERE calendar_date IN (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATE) 
                      , CAST('2013-06-03' AS DATE));

SELECT * FROM sys_calendar.calendar
WHERE calendar_date IN (CAST('2012-06-01' AS DATE) - 365
                      , CAST('2013-06-01' AS DATE) - 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why, but Teradata's parser always complains when you try to add anything else but literals to an IN-clause.

To get rid of the CAST is easy, just use the recommended syntax for date literals:

```
DATE '2012-06-01'
```

But when you need a calculation you have to switch to an ORed condition:

```
WHERE calendar_date = DATE '2012-06-01' - 365
   OR calendar_date = DATE '2013-06-01' - 1;
```

Dieter

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the Teradata SQL manual for the `IN/NOT IN` entry. An `IN` statement contains either:

- an expression
- a range of signed constants
- a list of constants

You can't have a list of expressions, i.e. doing date arithmetic on the fly like I had.

> If IN is used with a single-term operator, that operator can be a
>   constant or an expression. If a multiple-term operator is used, that
>   operator must consist of constants; expressions are not allowed.